# Substitue Escape for Control U in Terminal

Tags: keyboard, terminal

I would like to change `bash` keybinding so that the Escape key has the same effect as Control U. For example, if I tap the Escape key, the current Terminal command will be cleared out (which is what Control U does). How can I specify both the Escape key and the Control modifier when writing a new key definition in my .bash_profile?

Comment: Do you want to have Escape behave the same way as currently Ctrl-U does or the other way round? Either way, which key function are you trying to duplicate (what do you want both keys to do afterwards)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I want Escape to behave like Control U does; I want Escape to clear the current command from Terminal.

Comment: With the various functions the Esc key has in bash (primarily for command-line editing both in emacs and vi mode) this might not be very useful (or break a lot of other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind '"\e":"\C-u"'` doesn't have any effect, and escape can't be remapped from Terminal's preferences.

iTerm 2 does allow remapping escape:

[image]

0x05 0x15 is C-e C-u. (E is 0x45 and U is 0x55.)

You could also use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

The last two options  would prevent using escape in for example vi though.